# Is there a non-measurable set with measurable sections?

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the following fragments from [Axler's book "Measure, Integration and Real analysis"](http://measure.axler.net/)

[image]

I honestly don't know how to find the desired set $E$. I can't even find a single set $E \notin \mathcal{B}\otimes \mathcal{B}$, let alone one with the property we are looking for!

A hint into the right direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $F$ be your favorite subset of $\mathbb R$ that is *not* Borel measurable and define $$E\equiv\{(x,x)\,|\,x\in F\}.$$ Then, for every $x\in\mathbb R$,
\begin{align*}
[E]_x=[E]^x=\begin{cases}\{x\}&\text{if $x\in F$,}\\\varnothing&\text{if $x\notin F$,}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
which is clearly Borel measurable in either case.

However, $E\notin\mathcal B\otimes\mathcal B$. To see this, consider the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ defined as $f(x)\equiv(x,x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$. The function $f$ is continuous, so it is all the more so $\mathcal B/(\mathcal B\otimes B)$-measurable. Now, if $E$ were to be a member of $\mathcal B\otimes\mathcal B$, then we would have $F=f^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal B$, which is a contradiction given the initial assumption that $F\notin\mathcal B$.

Comment: I should have thought about that. The previous exercise wanted me to show that the diagonal is measurable when $F$ is!

Comment: @user745578 I don’t blame you. Measure theory can be so tricky in general that one is sometimes tempted to overthink even the relatively simple problems...

Comment: Well, the theoretical problems are easier to me than the "give an example problems". I usually always try $\Bbb{Q}$ or the Cantor set when I have to give counterexamples haha

Comment: The exercise discussed above comes from a book recently published in Springer's Graduate Texts in Mathematics series. This book is also in Springer's Open Access program. Thus the electronic version of the book is legally free to the world. It can be downloaded at http://measure.axler.net/ .